# restarting a python script when memory usage is too high

Tags: memory-management, python-2.7

I have a server written in python that would use a lot of RES memory when occasionally certain input comes in. It'd be annoying to have that python script continuously occupying that much RAM because we have a lot of other things running on the same machine. I did some research and found that the only sure way to release those memory back to the OS is to exit the process. So I am hoping to be able to restart the python script when it detects itself using too much memory after processing each input.

I tried the following trick to reload the process, and but found the process still uses as much RAM after reloading. No cleanup is done.

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)
```

Is there another clean way to restart a python script without inheriting all this RAM usage?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in a similar situation myself. I haven't come up with a solution yet, but what you might be able to do is make a bash script or .bat file that restarts the script when it finishes. This would most likely not inherit all that RAM because python itself exits and then starts again.

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)
```

This doesn't work because when you call os.execl it spawns a new process within the original python script and waits until that finishes, and then exits. That's why it "inherits" the RAM because it's still running in the background and hasn't exited yet.